# Geodesics and gradient flow

Tags: riemannian-geometry, geodesics, gradient-flows

Is there a construction in Riemannian geometry which relates the gradient flow of a function on a manifold with a certain metric with geodesics on another related manifold with its own metric?

Comment: Well, geodesic flow is a skew-gradient flow for the riemannian metric.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that a bit? Or give me a reference?

Comment: geodesic flow is a skew-gradient flow for the riemannian metric on the tangent bundle with standard symplectic form.